# Google Analytics in Android - filter out test device

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to make it so that my testing device doesn't report back on my Google Analytics when I open my Android app? I know with AdMob you can add test devices and those devices will load dummy ads. Is there something similar for Analytics on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your analytics client in "debug" mode, so it won't send any data.  (If you're using v2: see the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced#opt-out), if you're using v1: see the "Testing" section of [this overview](http://bitiotic.com/blog/2012/05/20/mapping-google-analytics-to-an-android-game-with-libgdx/)).

Alternatively, on the server side, you can have GA filter out clients based on domain or IP.  See http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033162

Comment: I guess that works. Not sure why Google didn't build in a similar feature as how it works in AdMob, but at least I can turn on debug mode on the builds I use on my devices. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer below, I don't think that P.T's solution would filter out the device.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's already answered, but IMHO that answer is incorrect.

According to: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced#opt-out putting the client in demo mode won't stop it sending data, it will just add debug info to LogCat. Instead you could use the setAppOptOut() explained in the same link.