# Filter My iPhone from Google Analytics iOS Mobile SDK Reports

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics to track users in my native iPhone app (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/).

Is it possible to block my own iPhone from the reports? I am tracking a Custom Dimension that I can use to uniquely identify my own iPhone. Is it possible to use this Custom Dimension in a filter for all of my Reports?

Comment: Just put your Device Id in test device. This is duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116475/google-analytics-in-android-filter-out-test-device